# How to redirect forward from one subdomain to another subdomain with DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain, cname-record, a-record

I have several subdomains under an existing main domain, e.g.:

```
eg.domain1.com
ie.domain1.com
```

The company is rebranding, and has setup a new main domain, under which all of these subdomains now need to exist under the same DNS IP Addresses, e.g.:

```
eg.domain2.com
ie.domain2.com
```

I need to have the old subdomains redirected/forwarded to the new subdomains, e.g:

```
sub.domain1.com -> sub.domain2.com
dom.domain1.com -> dom.domain2.com
```

Both domains are hosted on Network Solutions. I tried setting up web forwarding to do the redirect, but Network Solutions says that this is not possible with web forwarding, and offered no help in finding any other solutions.

I have also tried deleting the A records for the "old" domain and adding a CNAME record to alias the old subdomains to the new subdomain, but after waiting 18 hours or so, the change still hasn't taken effect.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. Period.

DNS does not do browser redirects. What you do is have a website react to the old domains and issuing a HTTP Permanent Redirect (response 301).

A redirect like this CAN NOT BE DONE IN DNS.

Now, this may not be possible with Network Solutions hosting - but that is THEIR limitation, not a technical one.

Comment: Tomtom not directly but a came would also work, but rewrite would be the preferred option. And moreover dons updates can take days depending on what TTL you set. Normally first decrease it wait some days and then do your dns work

Comment: So, I'll need to create a whole new server to host the old websites with different IP Addresses and redirect to the new ones from the webserver?

Comment: For example. That is how I would do it.

Comment: Appreciate the honest, solid answer @TomTom. Working on a solution now...